# Checking password strength while honoring functional requirements

Tags: python, python-3.x

A program needs a password strength estimator but has several implementation restrictions:

- Nothing outside of Python's standard library may be used.
- A database of common passwords may not be consulted.
- The code must be simple, self-contained, and easy to verify.

As for the interface of the password strength estimator, several requirements are provided:

- Empty passwords must have a strength of zero.
- Passwords may only use ASCII whitespace, alphanumeric, and punctuation characters.
- Passwords with other characters must have a strength less than zero.
- Otherwise, strength must be estimated as the bit-space needed to store the password.

In keeping with the caveats listed above, the following function appears to do as required:

```
import math
import string


def estimate_quality(password):
    if not password:
        return 0
    types = ([False, frozenset(string.whitespace)],
             [False, frozenset(string.ascii_lowercase)],
             [False, frozenset(string.ascii_uppercase)],
             [False, frozenset(string.digits)],
             [False, frozenset(string.punctuation)])
    for character in password:
        for index, (flag, group) in enumerate(types):
            if character in group:
                types[index][0] = True
                break
        else:
            return -1
    space = sum(len(group) for flag, group in types if flag)
    return math.ceil(math.log2(space) * len(password))
```

Is it possible to refactor the code to improve upon the third implementation restriction?

Comment: *Otherwise, strength must be estimated as the bit-space needed to store the password.* – You are not planning to store the password in plaint text, are you?

Comment: @RichardNeumann No, the password is used to generate an initialization vector and a cipher key and is never stored. Incremental decryption can be used to verify if the password was correct.

Comment: " Incremental decryption can be used to verify if the password was correct." - No, no, no, no!!!  You really, *really* need to feed the password into a password hashing function like PKBDF2, bcrypt, or scrypt.  Your password database *will* leak at some point, and without an expensive hash function, attackers can just run the most popular hundred million passwords through the encryption algorithm and pick out everyones password - which they can then try on higher value sites like gmail/facebook/etc.

Comment: @MartinBonner You made several assumptions that turn out to be false: (1) In generating an IV and CK, I never said that hashing was not involved. (2) I never said that there is a password database; there is none. (3) I never said passwords could instantly be verified; verification is expensive.

Comment: On point 1, yup, that was an incorrect assumption.  On point 2, you must have **something** that is stored, and is unique to each user, otherwise there is no way to verify the user has supplied the **correct** password.  I still worry that you are inventing a DIY scheme, rather than using a tried and tested scheme - but here is not the place to have that discussion.  If you want to check your scheme, you could ask about it on security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @MartinBonner That **something** is each individual message built by the user. It is a standalone GUI application that stores nothing but its settings on disk. Messages are transferred via the clipboard, and security on the OS is not a concern. To be honest, the program is a thought toy. **Reference:** [Wabol Talk](https://bitbucket.org/stephen-paul-chappell/csc-python-gui-programming/src/0cfb4660287832ef2ad2904581d715b67951f440/examples/Wabol%20Talk/Wabol%20Talk%200.9.2/Wabol%20Talk%200.9.2.pyw?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#Wabol%20Talk%200.9.2.pyw-859)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Your flags shouldn't be in the `types` definition.
- `types` should be a constant, move it out of the function.
- It'd be simpler if you used `set.__isub__` and `set.__and__`, and looped through the types array.

  It leaves all the unwanted values in the password too. Allowing for possible improvements on point 3.
- You can join the `sum` and the base `for` loop together, removing the need for a `types` list.

```
TYPES = (
    frozenset(string.whitespace),
    frozenset(string.ascii_lowercase),
    frozenset(string.ascii_uppercase),
    frozenset(string.digits),
    frozenset(string.punctuation)
)

def estimate_quality(password):
    if not password:
        return 0

    password_set = set(password)
    space = 0
    for group in TYPES:
        if password_set & group:
            space += len(group)
        password_set -= group

    if password_set:
        return -1

    return math.ceil(math.log2(space) * len(password))
```

Answer (score 4):

I would split this in 2 extra methods: 1 checking for the allowed characters, the other to check whether the char_type is used in the password

```
import itertools
import math
import string

default_allowed_char_types = (
    frozenset(string.whitespace),
    frozenset(string.ascii_lowercase),
    frozenset(string.ascii_uppercase),
    frozenset(string.digits),
    frozenset(string.punctuation),
)
```

a `tuple` of `frozensets` to prevent mutation

```
def check_allowed_characters(password, allowed_types=default_allowed_char_types):
    allowed_chars = set(itertools.chain(*allowed_types))
    return all(ch in allowed_chars for ch in password)

def type_used_in_password(password, char_type):
    return char_type.isdisjoint(password)

def calculate_strength(password, allowed_types=default_allowed_char_types):
    if not password:
        return 0
    if not check_allowed_characters(password, allowed_types):
        return -1
    space = sum(len(char_type) for char_type in allowed_types if type_used_in_password(password, char_type=type))
    return math.ceil(math.log2(space) * len(password))
```

Each of those 2 subfunctions can be easily tested individually

Comment: Putting the one-liner `char_type.isdisjoint(password)` into an own function with the even longer name `type_used_in_password(password, char_type)` does not seem sensible to me.

Comment: @RichardNeumann At first I had a different implementation for that part. When improving that function I just didn't think about taking it out. Now you can decide to inline this or leave this abstraction to test this part separately

Comment: If you follow my method, you can change `check_allowed_characters` to `return not functools.reduce(operator.sub, TYPES, set(password))`. Which IMO is a little easier to understand.